# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have get an unexpected error while implementing auth.guard in my Angular project. 
I get it on link click which is guarded by auth.guard.

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  CanActivate,
  Router,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from "@angular/router";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  private url: string;
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  private handleAuthState(): boolean {
    if (this.isLoginOrRegister()) {
      this.router.navigate(["/rentals"]);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  private handleNotAuthState(): boolean {
    if (this.isLoginOrRegister()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    return false;
  }
  private isLoginOrRegister(): boolean {
    if (this.url.includes("login") || this.url.includes("register")) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      return this.handleAuthState();
    }
    return this.handleNotAuthState();
  }
}
```

error in the console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at AuthGuard.push../src/app/auth/shared/auth.guard.ts.AuthGuard.isLoginOrRegister (auth.guard.ts:30)
    at AuthGuard.push../src/app/auth/shared/auth.guard.ts.AuthGuard.handleAuthState (auth.guard.ts:16)
    at AuthGuard.push../src/app/auth/shared/auth.guard.ts.AuthGuard.canActivate (auth.guard.ts:43)
    at router.js:3103
    at Observable._subscribe (defer.js:9)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at TakeOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/take.js.TakeOperator.call (take.js:24)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:24)
    at subscribeTo.js:21
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:15724
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15772
next @ core.js:17771
schedulerFn @ core.js:13515
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13499
(anonymous) @ core.js:17321
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17258
onHandleError @ core.js:17321
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:164
_loop_1 @ zone.js:694
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:703
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:608
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:502
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
```

[error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edfwA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Well, `.includes` appear in exactly two places in your script, both times as `this.url.includes`. After declaring the property `url`, nothing else (particularly: assignment) ever happens to it.

(And BTW, instead of `if (someBooleanExpression) return true; else return false;`, you can simply `return someBooleanExpression`.)

Answer (score 0):

Posting, just to explain what happened.

You have this line

```
let url: string = state.url;
```

which declares method scoped variable url, while the class property, declared above, stay not initialised:

```
  private url: string;
```

So changing to

```
this.url = state.url;
```

should solve it as the error message is on this line

```
this.url.includes("login") || this.url.includes("register"))
```

and it says that the property is null which is true, you didn't initialised it yet

Comment: Did this help you as you said before?

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look upon `AuthGuard.isLoginOrRegister (auth.guard.ts:30)` part.

You should handle an **exception handler** such as below.
Refer the following `// HERE` comments:

```
private isLoginOrRegister(): boolean {
  // HERE
  if (this.url && (this.url.includes("login") || this.url.includes("register"))) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
...

canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): boolean {
  // HERE
  this.url = state.url;

  if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    return this.handleAuthState();
  }
  return this.handleNotAuthState();
}
```

Hope it'd help you.